# When trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist'

Tags: django

I am trying to run command:  `python3 manage.py runserver 0:80` and I get the below error

Exception in thread django-main-thread:

> Traceback (most recent call last):File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner self.run() File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run                                                                                                                                                                                     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                                  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper                                                                                                                                                  fn(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run                                                                                                                             self.check(display_num_errors=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 423, in check                                                                                                                                               databases=databases,                                                                                                                                                                                                                       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks                                                                                                                                           new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)                                                                                                                                                                           File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config                                                                                                                                         return check_resolver(resolver)                                                                                                                                                                                                            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver                                                                                                                                           return check_method()                                                                                                                                                                                                                      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 416, in check                                                                                                                                                     for pattern in self.url_patterns:                                                                                                                                                                                                          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in **get**                                                                                                                                                  res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)                                                                                                                                                                                   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 602, in url_patterns                                                                                                                                              patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)                                                                                                                                                                File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in **get**                                                                                                                                                  res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)                                                                                                                                                                                   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 595, in urlconf_module                                                                                                                                            return import_module(self.urlconf_name)                                                                                                                                                                                                    File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module                                                                                                                                                                  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                                                                                                                File "", line 994, in _gcd_import                                                                                                                                                                               File "", line 971, in _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                                            File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                            File "", line 678, in exec_module                                                                                                                                                                      File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                 File "/home/rc/qrd/qos-dashboard/config/urls.py", line 4, in                                                                                                                                                                           from rest_framework_swagger.views import get_swagger_view                                                                                                                                                                                  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework_swagger/views.py", line 3, in                                                                                                                                              from rest_framework.renderers import CoreJSONRenderer                                                                                                                                                                                      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 24, in                                                                                                                                                 from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status                                                                                                                                                                        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 25, in                                                                                                                                               from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist                                                                                                                                                                                    ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                             File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in **getitem**                                                                                                                                                return self._engines[alias]                                                                                                                                                                                                              KeyError: 'django'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                             File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries                                                                                                                           module = import_module(entry[1])                                                                                                                                                                                                           File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module                                                                                                                                                                  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                                                                                                                File "", line 994, in _gcd_import                                                                                                                                                                               File "", line 971, in _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                                            File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                            File "", line 678, in exec_module                                                                                                                                                                      File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py", line 15, in                                                                                                                               from rest_framework.renderers import HTMLFormRenderer                                                                                                                                                                                      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 24, in                                                                                                                                                 from rest_framework import VERSION, exceptions, serializers, status                                                                                                                                                                        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 25, in                                                                                                                                               from django.db.models.fields import FieldDoesNotExist                                                                                                                                                                                    ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                             File "manage.py", line 22, in                                                                                                                                                                                                          execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                                                                                                                                        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line                                                                                                                       utility.execute()                                                                                                                                                                                                                          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 413, in execute                                                                                                                                         self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)                                                                                                                                                                                    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv                                                                                                                                       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)                                                                                                                                                                                                         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute                                                                                                                                super().execute(*args, **options)                                                                                                                                                                                                          File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute                                                                                                                                             output = self.handle(*args, **options)                                                                                                                                                                                                     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 96, in handle                                                                                                                                 self.run(**options)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 103, in run                                                                                                                                   autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)                                                                                                                                                                                    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 638, in run_with_reloader                                                                                                                                       start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 623, in start_django                                                                                                                                            reloader.run(django_main_thread)                                                                                                                                                                                                           File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 328, in run                                                                                                                                                     autoreload_started.send(sender=self)                                                                                                                                                                                                       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 182, in send                                                                                                                                                 for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)                                                                                                                                                                                               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 182, in                                                                                                                                            for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)                                                                                                                                                                                               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 44, in watch_for_template_changes                                                                                                                            for directory in get_template_directories():                                                                                                                                                                                               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/autoreload.py", line 17, in get_template_directories                                                                                                                              for backend in engines.all():                                                                                                                                                                                                              File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all                                                                                                                                                        return [self[alias] for alias in self]                                                                                                                                                                                                     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in                                                                                                                                                  return [self[alias] for alias in self]                                                                                                                                                                                                     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in **getitem**                                                                                                                                                engine = engine_cls(params)                                                                                                                                                                                                                File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in **init**                                                                                                                                         options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)                                                                                                                                                                           File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries                                                                                                                        libraries = get_installed_libraries()                                                                                                                                                                                                      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries                                                                                                                         for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):                                                                                                                                                                                                    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 126, in get_package_libraries                                                                                                                           ) from e                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework': cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist'

I am trying to run the django code in local or migrate it even. It should have been with no error/warnings, but suddenly today I am getting all these warnings.
Earlier it was related to library 'six' which resolved thru: `pip install django-utils-six`. I even installed `mysqlclient 2.0.1` before that.